# Server 2012 R2 Essentials IIS DefaultTSGateway variable

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-terminal-services

So I want to use RDP externally so have a forwarded domain so /remote then downlaoding RDP file works. However, I get gateway errors (Your computer can't connect to the remote computer because the Remote Desktop Gateway server is temporarily unavailable.) and have read that I need to change the variable `DefaultTSGateway` under RDWeb then Pages and on another site TS however I do not see either of these under my `Default Web Site`. Where can I find them to change?

Comment: Telling us exactly what you're doing and exactly what errors you get would sure;y be helpful.

Comment: I don’t know where to find errors, I couldn’t find any logs

Comment: You said `"I get gateway errors"`... so what are those errors?

Comment: Oh my bad editing question in a moment

Comment: @joeqwerty I’ve added error details

Answer (score 0):

Inside IIS, expand Sites, Default Web Site, RDWeb, Pages. While on "Pages", click the Application settings icon in the middle. You see the DefaultTSGateway there, most probably with unassigned value.